# Extracting .so file in android exposes hardcoded strings. How to avoid that?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_commonutils_Encryption_APIKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject object){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "test123");
}
```

Here extracting the so file exposes the value test123

Comment: The short answer is: encode the string in some other way than plain ASCII/Unicode, and make sure you decode it back before using it. But there are many different ways in which you could accomplish this - and unless you want it to be trivial for anyone to figure out the encoding, things can get very complicated. As such, your question is really broad and probably not a good fit for StackOverflow. Try doing some research first, e.g. googling _"elf encryption"_ and reading the material that you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial way would be assigning characters one-by-one instead of through string literals.

For example,

```
char dummy[8] = {0};
dummy[0] = 't';
dummy[1] = 'e';
dummy[2] = 's';
dummy[3] = 't';
dummy[4] = '1';
dummy[5] = '2';
dummy[6] = '3';
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, dummy);
```